# How to iterate over names and values in Julia NamedTuple?

Tags: tuples, julia, iteration

E.g. if I have:

```
t = (
  a = 1:5,
  b = 2:6,
  c = 3:7,
)
```

And I'd like:

```
(
  a = 15,
  b = 20,
  c = 25,
)
```

What's an idiomatic way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want

```
julia> map(sum, t)
(a = 15, b = 20, c = 25)
```

Comment: just a caveat, it does not work with dictionaries, only named tuples

Answer (score 2):

i don't know how to pass from `1:5` to `15`, but if you allow me to invent such function, then, you could do:

```
julia> NamedTuple(k=>length(v)*(first(v)+2) for (k,v) in pairs(t))
(a = 15, b = 20, c = 25)
```

Comment: hahaha, it was just `sum`, i overcomplicated myself

Comment: well, this question seems a bit of a quiz..

Comment: this actually helped me the most since I was looking for a way to grab the ith element of each part of the tuple. this showed how the code could generalize.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use good old `map`:

```
julia> map(x -> length(x) * (first(x) + 2), t)
(a = 15, b = 20, c = 25)
```